# insert data if not exist in MySql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I already found the MySQL query that I want to use

```
INSERT INTO tbl_time_in (studentID, studentDAY, studentDATE, studentTIME_IN, temp_schedule_ID)
SELECT *  
FROM (SELECT 'rupert', 'Tuesday', 'June 29, 2016' ,'23:20', '59') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT studentID 
                  FROM tbl_time_in 
                  WHERE studentID = 'rupert' and studentDATE = 'June 29, 2016' and temp_schedule_ID = '59')
```

but I also want to know how could I implement this in C# correctly.

I tried to use `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` but it always gives an empty result.

Comment: What do you want to return?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL database you can use the **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** function this will lessen using of sub query. Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for further references.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can implement this in if else statement, using a integer counter to check is the data exists or not, 
1st fire the count statement and store the result in an integer, 
2nd compare the the result with a 0 value 
- if result > 0 then the data exists in the database, 
else 
 (it means result = 0)
do insert Query